# Bring the parameter name along with breadcrumb

Tags: angular, breadcrumbs

I am working with angular2 and I am using breadcrumb in my project. Following is my router.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "Home",
    component: RootComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "Create/:Type",
        component: CreateComponent,
        data: {
          breadcrumb: "Create"
        }
      },
      {
        path: "Edit/:id",
        component: EditComponent,
        data: {
          breadcrumb: "Edit"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

So my Breadcrumb may be like **Home \ Create** or **Home \ Edit**. My requirement is, in the case of **Create** there also pass a parameter called 'Type'. Can I integrate its value also along with the breadcrumb. For example: Type='Profile'  then the breadcrumb will be like **Home \ Create-Profile** . Please help me.

Comment: Just pass the `Type` as a `queryParam` and pick it up by using `ActivatedRoute` when you are in `CreateComponent`

Comment: @Nehal the problem with your approach is that the only component that receives that value as param is the target one. And is not always the case. Also, extract manually from ActivatedRoute make the breadcrumb totally dependent on the app. Which shouldn't be.